# Failed application install seems to have corrupted apt-get, how do I force it to forget?

Tags: 11.04, apt, boxee

My HTPC is running ubuntu 11.04 and I tried installing boxee a while back.  I got it to install, but everytime I try to use apt-get now, it says:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 boxee : Depends: libxmlrpc-c3 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

If I run `apt-get -f install` it prompts me to uninstall Boxee. Now, Boxee is installed and very functional, I don't wish to uninstall it. How do I essentially make apt forget about Boxee and libxmlrpc-c3?

edit: the output of apt-cache policy boxee is:

```
$ apt-cache policy boxee
boxee:
  Installed: 0.9.22.13692
  Candidate: 0.9.22.13692
  Version table:
 *** 0.9.22.13692 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

edit: **solution** --

As suggested, I `apt-get -f install`'d, it removed boxee.  I then re-installed and everything is working well.

Comment: How did you install boxee exactly ? a ppa ? Try running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: It has been a while since I installed it unfortunately.  I had an older version installed perfectly fine, I then upgraded to a newer version and that's where I had dependency issues.  I removed (or so I thought) the newer version and reverted back to an older one. I used `dpkg` to install the current version, but I'm not sure what I used for the newer version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boxee : Depends: libxmlrpc-c3 but it is not installable` means that boxee's dependencies are not fully installed, so it may not work properly (note: I'm not saying that it won't work, just that some functions may not work).

To fix the problem, the easiest thing to do is to follow `apt-get`'s advice and uninstall it. Uninstallation won't make you lose your configuration nor your files. Once `apt-get -f install` has finished, you will be able to install boxee again using:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install boxee
```

If this last command shows errors, then it'd be better to get in touch with the administrator of the archive from which you got boxee. The output of `apt-cache policy boxee` may be helpful.

Comment: To be honest, part of my apprehension stemmed from not knowing if I really needed to uninstall it. Knowing that I probably do gives me the courage to explain to my wife why I'm _fiddling with the tv again_.

Comment: I went through with it and uninstalled/reinstalled. With the issues I had with the newest version I was putting it off, but everything is fine now.  Thanks :)